# Instagram private api direct message like/unlike

Tags: node.js, api, instagram-api

I am working on instagram-private-api with nodejs. Trying to implement like/unlike functionality for a direct message in a direct message thread.

I tried following two approaches. Both are not working and getting 500 error from instagram api call-

Code snippet 1-

```
const { IgApiClient, IgCheckpointError } = require('instagram-private-api');
this.ig = new IgApiClient();
this.ig.state.generateDevice(username);
this.ig.state.deserializeCookieJar(cookie);
const result = await this.ig.live.like(messageID,1);
```

Code snippet 2-

```
const { IgApiClient, IgCheckpointError } = require('instagram-private-api');
this.ig = new IgApiClient();
this.ig.state.generateDevice(username);
this.ig.state.deserializeCookieJar(cookie);
const result = await this.ig.media.like({
        mediaId: messageID, 
        moduleInfo: {
          module_name: 'profile',
          user_id: pk,
          username: username,
        },
        d:1
      });
```

username and cookie is proper as other api calls are working as expected.

Comment: How are you getting the messageId?

Comment: Using .net core to get inbox thread messages. Using InstaSharper 1.4.0 and messageId here is InstaSharper.Classes.Models.ItemId